# Reading data from Excel file in r

Tags: r

I want to read data from a big excel file like this:

From the fifth column, from first row until 140, but only 1,3,5,7,.....139 (only 70 values):

```
wb <- loadWorkbook("D:\\MA\\excel_mix_meiningen.xlsx")
dat <-readWorksheet(wb, sheet=getSheets(wb)[1], startRow=1, endRow=139, startCol=5, endCol=5)
odds <- function(x) {seq(1, length(x), 2)}
odds(unlist(dat))
```

but I get this error:

```
Error: OutOfMemoryError (Java): Java heap space
```

Is there another way to do this job?

Comment: What package are you using? Can you provide a reproducible example (perhaps attach a small excel file that reproduces your error)?

Comment: I am using `XlConnect` Package

Comment: have you considered the `xlsx` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/vignettes/XLConnect.pdf) on `XlConnect` suggests

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx2048m")
```

before loading the `XlConnect` package.

EDIT:
You could try to reduce the size of the xlsx, maybe delete unneeded columns.
You could save the sheet as CSV.
You could use RODBC, as @Ananta suggested.

Comment: thank you for your answer, if I change my code to: `options(java.parameters = "-Xmx2048m" )
library(XLConnect)
wb <- loadWorkbook("D:\\MA\\excel_mix_meiningen.xlsx")` I get the error as before :/

Comment: how much is your RAM and how big is that excel file

Comment: @Ananta My Ram:4,00 GB(3,5 GB usable) nad the excel file is 138 MB. I am using windows 7 32-bit

Comment: did  you try changing the heapsize before loading the package? try that if not, may be look in other package I think RODBC works well.